# How do deal with SQL Server transaction log corruption

Tags: sql-server-2008, corruption, database-backup, transaction-log

We had a failure with our SQL Server log shipping job. sp_readerrorlog reported:

> Backup detected log corruption in database X. Context is Bad Middle Sector. LogFile: 2 'D:\Database\X_log.MDF' VLF SeqNo: x3f116 VLFBase: x1ede0000 LogBlockOffset: x1f55f600 SectorStatus: 2 LogBlock.StartLsn.SeqNo: x3f116 LogBlock.StartLsn.Blk: x3bf8 Size: x1800 PrevSize: x1400

We've checked the disk for errors; nothing found. So it's not really clear why the log is corrupt, but obviously we'll need to get the log shipping going again.

One possible way forward is documented in this post I found:
http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/How-can-a-log-backup-fail-but-a-full-backup-succeed.aspx

...but wondering if anybody else has seen this happen, and would appreciate any other thoughts as to root cause for this behaviour, and other ways of dealing with the issue.

Comment: I believe if you ask this question on [Database Administrators site of StackExchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) you will have better response.

Comment: Thanks. Further investigation found one of the drives had raised an alert (which hadn't been delivered properly) related to predictive fault detection (I didn't catch the actual buzzword).

We also found that it wasn't necessary to jump through as many hoops as listed in the sqlskills link above to get the log shipping running again; better brains than I determined that it worked fine without having to put take the database offline.